# Docker with Vite - env variables are undefined inside the docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, environment-variables, vite

I'm building a react project with Vite, and I'm new to Docker, and when I created a docker file, all was good, but the env variables are always undefined inside the Docker container.

Here's my simple `Dockerfile` ...

```
FROM node:18.17.1-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm","run","preview"]
```

And here's the `.dockerignore` file ...

```
README.md
build
dist
node_modules
LICENSE
package-lock.json
.git
.DS_Store
.env
```

And here's the `.env` file ...

```
VITE_API_BASE_URL=https://example.com
```

And this is how I'm accessing the env variable inside the code ...

```
import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL
```

Whenever I build the Docker image and run the Docker container, the `VITE_API_BASE_URL` is always undefined in the `network` tab, however when I remove the `.env` from the `.dockerignore` file and build the image again and run it, it works fine.
But obviously that's not the solution, I need the app to be able to read the env variables inside the Dockere container.

What can I do?

Comment: And how exactly _are_ you trying to set the env vars on the running container? Note that they're likely required at _build_ time, not runtime (which is a problem for reasons I expand on in https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not exactly sure what you mean, this is all I have, I'm new to Docker. But this is how I'm trying to read the env variable in my code `import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL`

Comment: I'm not asking how you're trying to access them in the code, I'm asking how you're trying to provide them to the container. If the answer is that you aren't, then there's the problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Aha, got it. So I'll search on that point, that's what the missing piece of the puzzle. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who are struggling, and thanks to @jonrsharpe comment, here's what you need to do ...

You need to pass the Env variables to your Docker container somehow, what worked for me was passing the variables during the Docker image build, NOT when running the container, by creating a build args in your `Dockerfile` like this ...

```
FROM node:18.17.1-alpine

# Define build arguments for environment variables
ARG VITE_API_BASE_URL
ARG VITE_API_KEY

# Set environment variables during the build process
ENV VITE_API_BASE_URL=$VITE_API_BASE_URL
ENV VITE_API_KEY=$VITE_API_KEY

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

# Rest of your Dockerfile...

# For example:
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "preview"]
```

Then you can pass the values of those args to your Docker image build command like this ...

```
docker build \
  --build-arg VITE_API_BASE_URL=https://example.com \
  --build-arg VITE_API_KEY=A12O6f90eCfMFf8 \
  -t your-image-name .
```

That's it.

Comment: I was in similar line and this works for passing env variables on build time, how to update this at run time or while starting the container.

Comment: This is nonsense!
How should I use one container for dev, stage, prod?
I will have to create 3 different images and use them...

Answer (score -1):

I got to work passing env variable when running the container.

In my `.env.production` file in vite project I put the values in a standard starting with `MY_APP_`

```
VITE_API_SMARTGLPI_BACKEND=MY_APP_API_SMARTGLPI_BACKEND
VITE_SAC_NTINF_URL=MY_APP_SAC_NTINF_URL
```

So, I created a `env.sh` script with the content below:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(env | grep MY_APP_)
do
    key=$(echo $i | cut -d '=' -f 1)
    value=$(echo $i | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
    echo $key=$value
    # sed All files
    # find /usr/share/nginx/html -type f -exec sed -i "s|${key}|${value}|g" '{}' +

    # sed JS and CSS only
    find /usr/share/nginx/html -type f \( -name '*.js' -o -name '*.css' \) -exec sed -i "s|${key}|${value}|g" '{}' +
done
```

This script will be executed when the container get up and will change the values `MY_APP_API_SMARTGLPI_BACKEND` and `MY_APP_SAC_NTINF_URL` inside **js** and **css** code, replacing this values for the env vars informed on docker-compose.

I created a `Dockerfile` with the content

```
FROM node:20.7.0-alpine as BUILD_IMAGE
WORKDIR /app/react-app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine as PRODUCTION_IMAGE
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/react-app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY env.sh /docker-entrypoint.d/env.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.d/env.sh
```

As you can see, I copied the `env.sh` to inside `/docker-entrypoint.d` directory of nginx container. All script inside this directory will be executed as soon the container get up.

So, I created the `docker-compose.yml` file with the content below:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app:
    image: app-image:v1.0 
    environment:
      MY_APP_API_SMARTGLPI_BACKEND: "URL_BACKEND"
      MY_APP_SAC_NTINF_URL: "URL_SAC_NTINF"
```

More datails, you can see in https://dev.to/sanjayttg/dynamic-environment-variables-for-dockerized-react-apps-5bc5